# Capturing a 'delete' key press

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, keypress

I can't figure out how to capture the <kbd>Delete</kbd>key press.
I found out that in ASCII code table, it is at 127 place, but `if (Key = #127) then` got me nowhere.

Then I checked the value of `VK_DELETE` which was 47. Tried to use that, but it didn't work.

The `KeyPreview := true` is set in my form.

I tried to add the `ShowMessage(IntToStr(Ord(Key)))` to the Forms KeyPress event, but I never got the message popup while clicking the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

I need to handle the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key press in dynamicaly created Edit fields. I want to control what part of the text user can erase in that field, and I know how to handle the text deletion using <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, now need to figure out how to do it with <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should handle the `OnKeyDown` instead of the `OnKeyPress` event. If you do that then `VK_DELETE` should work for you. Note that the parameter for  `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` is a `Word`, not a `Char` as for `OnKeyPress`.

Answer (score 14):

Mghie has the correct answer, here is a sample:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   if Key=VK_DELETE then
     showmessage('Delete key was pressed');
end;
```

Note that the user can also delete text using cut-to-clipboard so you may need to handle that as well.

Comment: You can also delete text by selecting it and then typing new text.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, it is easily avoidable. I can check what part of text is selected in the KeyPress event before letting user to write something.

Answer (score 4):

You can use OnKeyDown event to filter the undesired <kbd>Delete</kbd> key pressed:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift:
    TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_DELETE then begin
    Beep;
    Key:= 0;
  end;
end;
```